# How can I set a file as an input variable in a bat file?

Tags: command-line

I'm wanting a bat file to drag'n drop files and open them with a program. The bat file goes as follows normally:

```
@echo off
C:\path\to\program\program.exe -variables "C:\path\to\file\randomfile.*"
```

Now, I want to keep the same structure but I want to set a variable to replace "randomfile.*", that variable being the file I drag'n drop, but I don't know how to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

#### How do I set a variable to replace `randomfile.*` when I drag and drop a file?

When you drag and drop a file onto a batch file the name of that file is passed as a parameter `%1` to the batch file.

To do this edit your batch file as follows:

```
@echo off
C:\path\to\program\program.exe -variables "%1"
```

Notes:

- You can get the value of any argument using a `%` followed by it's numerical position on the command line. The first item passed is always `%1`, the second item is always `%2` and so on.
- `%*` in a batch script refers to all the arguments (e.g. `%1 %2 %3 %4 %5 ... %255`)
- Only arguments `%1` to `%9` can be referenced by number.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [parameters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) - A command line argument (or parameter) is any value passed into a batch script.